# How to measure admittance in Simulink Matlab?

Tags: matlab, simulation, simulink

I need to measure admittance in my RLC. Is there any clever way to do it? I know that there is special block for impedance measuring, can I make use of that?

Comment: "can I make use of that?" I dont know, have you tried it?

Comment: No I don't becouse I don't know how to. Thats why I asked the question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> First of all I would like to reaffirm what Ander Biguri has suggested
>   in his comment. Before posting on Stack Overflow you should try
>   working things out by your own means (use the [documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/)), and if you don't succeed, then post a
>   question providing more details. This way more users will be able to
>   help you and you will get better answers.

This is an approach without using the Impedance Measurement block:

First I created a `simulink` model of an RLC circuit using the following blocks from the *Simscape Power Systems Specialized Technology Fundamental Blocks* Library ([`powerlib`](https://mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/ug/simpowersystems-block-libraries.html#btxy9ca-1)):

- AC Voltage Source
- Current Measurement
- Series RLC Branch
- Powergui

Aside from the AC Voltage Source block and the Series RLC Branch block, the Current Measurement block and the Powergui block are necessary for the model to work.

[image: Simulink model rlc circuit]

Since you did not provide any particular values for the circuit components, I am using the defaults.

Then I named the model as `my_rlc` and saved it in my working directory.

Finally, I created the following script (inspired by [this example](https://mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/powersys/ref/seriesrlcbranch.html#f3-2401586)) which makes use of the [`power_analyze`](https://mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/powersys/ref/power_analyze.html) function to obtain the [state-space model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-space_representation) of the circuit (`my_rlc`) from which the admittance can be obtained. Since the behaviour of an RLC circuit varies depending on the frequency, I used the [`bode`](https://mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/bode.html) function to obtain the magnitude and phase of the admittance for the range of frequency values spanning from 10 Hz to 10 kHz.

```
% Analyze electric circuit.
% Obtain the matrices (A,B,C,D) of the state-space model of the circuit.
[A, B, C, D] = power_analyze('my_rlc');

% Generate logarithmically spaced vector of frequency values.
% 500 points between decades 10^1 and 10^4.
freq = logspace(1, 4, 500);

% Vector of angular frequency values.
w = 2*pi*freq;

% Magnitude and phase of frequency response.
% Ymag: Admittance magnitude.
% Yphase: Admittance phase.
[Ymag, Yphase] = bode(A, B, C, D, 1, w);

% Plot Admittance magnitude.
subplot(2, 1, 1);
loglog(freq, Ymag);
grid on;
title('RLC Circuit');
xlabel('Frequency [Hz]');
ylabel('Admittance [S]');

% Plot Admittance phase.
subplot(2, 1, 2);
semilogx(freq, Yphase);
xlabel('Frequency [Hz]');
ylabel('Phase [deg]');
grid on;
```

This is the result:

[image: RLC circuit: Admittance Magnitude and Phase]

If you wish to know more about working with state-space models in `MATLAB`, I encourage you to read: [What Are State-Space Models?](https://mathworks.com/help/ident/ug/what-are-state-space-models.html)

Comment: Yeah, I know that I am supposed to do things myself first. My nad I didn't post my attemps to reach the point. Your solution is exactly what I needed, but I didn't came IP for idea to do it without an impedance block. Thank you very much!